# Creating new matrix from combining two other by using an if-statement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, matrix, replace

I have a matrix in dimension 8x6. Half of the elements in this matrix are 0, which is totally fine. Now, I would like to refer to another matrix which is 160x6. The 8x6 matrix is based on the 160x6 matrix and results from a rolling window (20 observations).

I would like to create a new matrix (again 160x6). Whenever an element in my 8x6 matrix equals 0, I would like the 20 observations from the original 160x6 matrix referring to this element (being 0) to be 0 as well.

I have tried the following:

```
for t=1:T
    for i=1:N
    if B(:,i) == 0;
    C(t,i) = 0;
    else
    C(t,i) = A(t,i);
    end
    end
end
```

where I have:

`A` being the 160x6 matrix

`B` being the 8x6 matrix

`C` being the new output as 160x6 matrix

At the moment, I obtain a "new" 160x6 matrix (`C`), but it exactly replicates the original 160x6 matrix (`A`). So the looping or the if statement is incorrect.

Comment: I assume `T = 160` and `N = 6` in this example?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry for leaving this out.

Comment: You also missed `A` and `B` matrices. It's easier giving an example having your input data.

Comment: `B(:,i) == 0 ` will never be true because you are comparing an entire column of a matrix with zero, unless you only have a single row in your matrix and thus `B(:,i)` is a scalar. That's why your C is same as A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

```
%Initialize A matrix with ones for testing.
A = ones(160, 6);
B = ones(8, 6);

%Put few zeros in B
B(1:2:end,1) = 0;
B(5:3:end,3) = 0;

T = 160;
N = 6;

for t=1:T
    for i=1:N
        %The formula k = floor((t-1)/20)+1 equals 1, 1, 1, 1... 20 times, then 2, 2, 2, 2... 20 times
        k = floor((t-1)/20)+1;
        if B(k,i) == 0;
            C(t,i) = 0;
        else
            C(t,i) = A(t,i);
        end
    end
end

%Display C as an image (for testing).
figure;imagesc(C);colormap gray
```

Image for testing result:
[image]

---

Values of k are demonstrated in the following graph:

```
T=160;t = 1:T;k = floor((t-1)/20)+1;figure;plot(t, k, 'x');grid on;
```

[image]

---

Most compact solution I could achieved:

```
C = A.*imresize((B ~= 0), size(A), 'nearest');
```

Comment: Hey Rotem. Wow! Thank you so much. The code is working and I could transfer it to my own code. I'm very thankful!

The formula you've added is great. ;) I just have one more question. Not relevant in my case, but still interested. 

In the given example, I have 8 periods with 20 obeservations each. Therefore, it perfectly matches the 160 overall observations. But what if I'd have let's say 165 observations? I think the code would leave out the last 5, because the index exceeds matrix dimensions right? Any chance to overcome this problem?

Comment: Assume 5 extra observations should be moved from A to C unchanged. Solution can be: **1.** Copy matrix A to C before the loop `C = A;` **2.** `t` iterates to maximum value that does not exceed matrix dimension (e.g up to `160`).  You can calculate upper value as follows: `floor(165/20)*20`.

Comment: In case 5 extra observations belongs to last element of `B`, you can modify the code to limit `k` before using it after `k = floor((t-1)/20)+1;`, add code `k = min(k, size(B,1));`

Comment: Hey Rotem, I am amazed by the great help that I received by all of your answers today. Thank you very much! I would have marked all three answers I got as 'useful', but appearently this does not work for freshers like me ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will give a small example based on my understanding of your problem.

```
>> B = randi(10,8,6) - 5; % Sample B matrix

B =

    -4     0    -4     4     5     1
    -2     3     3     1     3    -4
    -1     3     1    -3     1     4
     2     5     0    -2     0     4
    -3     4     5     4    -4     3
     3    -1     2    -4     2    -3
    -3     2     2     0    -4     2
     2    -3     4    -3    -4     1
```

In this matrix you want to identify the locations which have `0` e.g. (1,2), (4,3), (4,5). and in the 160 x 6 matrix (1:20,2), (61:80,3), (61:80,5) should be zero. You can use the `repelem` function to get such indexes.

```
>> zeroIdx = repelem(B == 0,20,1)
```

`zeroIdx` would contain true for wherever B is zero, with each row repeated twenty times.

```
>> C = A
>> C(zeroIdx) = 0 % Assign 0 to C using zeroIdx
```